Why OAUTH2 in spring security need to save access_token?
According to spring security, there is a service OAuth2AuthorizationService which has many implementations one of them is JdbcOAuth2AuthorizationService. This service saves token inside my db and the table which has this token is so huge that it is about 30% from all db storage. My question is why spring security need to save access_token even if it is jwt which is self contained token.
My question is why spring security need to save access_token even if it is jwt which is self contained token?

Spring Security's JdbcOAuth2AuthorizationService persists access tokens, including JWTs, for the following reasons:
1. Revocation Support
JWTs are self-contained and cannot be invalidated once issued without a persistent store to track invalidated tokens.
By saving tokens in the database, Spring Security enables token revocation, allowing administrators or systems to invalidate a token before its expiration. This is crucial in scenarios like compromised tokens or user logout.
2. Managing Refresh Tokens
Access tokens and refresh tokens are often managed together. When a refresh token is used to generate a new access token, the old access token is typically invalidated.
Persisting tokens in the database ensures this relationship is tracked, preventing old tokens from being used maliciously once refreshed. This adds a layer of security and lifecycle management to the token system.
While JWTs are stateless, these mechanisms ensure better control and security in token management, especially in complex applications.
